# Plastic/Glass for a very large, custom frame

Tags: glass, plastic, framing, acrylic-glass

I am working on a large poster to display my original Pokemon cards, but because of the size of the cards and the way I wanted them to be laid out, store bought frames are out of the question.  The poster is not 100% done so I am not sure what the final measurements will be once I trim down the poster board, but it probably will be 49 inches by 29 inches. All of the cards are in sleeves, but I still want something over all of it to keep the cards flat against the poster.  What kind of plastic or vinyl or glass (though I don't know how I'd cut it) would be cost effective (at most $25), easy enough to cut to size, and not a pain to apply (like with phone screen protectors, it is hard to get the bubbles out).  Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in glass? The title/tags seem to imply you are, but then you don't mention it in the question :)

Comment: Yes I am, I must have had a complete brain fart!

Comment: When this is complete your cards will be permanently mounted correct? Do you have any intention of getting them out again? You cost restrictions really limit your options here. Want to know though as we might still be able to do this. Also, why are store bought frames out of the question exactly?

Comment: I have no intention of getting them out.  And the cards are mounted on 1/8 foam core, plus the awkward size makes store bought frames a no go.  The nearest store that sells them to me is Walmart, and there is nothing else that is not over an hour drive.

Answer (score 1):

A clear Mylar sheet could work.

Clear, moisture resistant, acid free and archival.
And available in the size and price range you are looking for.

Here's an example available on Amazon 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0027A3HKG/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1473127673&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=clear+mylar+roll&dpPl=1&dpID=31N50Emps-L&ref=plSrch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027A3HKG)

Comment: Does that kind of material roll out flat or does it need heat? Also,does it have adhesive on it? I've gotten a roll of vinyl that had glue on one side and it was impossible to get flat.